# Wedge product of Lie algebra valued differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, self-learning, differential-forms

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be the Lie algebra of a matrix Lie group. Furthermore, let us consider the following $\mathfrak{g}$-valued $p$-form and $\mathfrak{g}$-valued $q$-form:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{cc}
\zeta = \zeta^\alpha \otimes T_\alpha \; ,& \eta = \eta^\alpha \otimes T_\alpha
\end{array}
\end{equation}
where $\zeta^\alpha \in \Omega^p(P)$, $\eta^\alpha \in \Omega^q(P)$ and $\{ T_\alpha \}$ is a basis of $\mathfrak{g}$. Then  I'm trying to show that:
\begin{equation}
\zeta \wedge \eta = T_\alpha T_\beta \zeta^\alpha \wedge \eta^\beta \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Can someone help me or give me a nudge in the right direction? The only possibility I see is using the definition:
\begin{equation}
(\zeta \wedge \eta)(X_1,\ldots,X_{p+q}) = \frac{1}{p!q!} \sum\limits_{P \in S_r} \mathrm{sgn}(P) \zeta(X_{P(1)},\ldots,X_{P(p)}) \eta (X_{P(p+1)},\ldots,X_{P(p+q)})
\end{equation}
but is don't really understand how to manipulate this in order to get equation $(1)$.

I'm not sure if the notation used above is conventional notation for mathematicians, so please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: I assume $T_\alpha T_\beta$ is the usual matrix product, so that you are talking about *matrix* Lie groups?

Comment: @geodude thanks for pointing that out. I've edited my question.

Comment: This answer appears to answer my question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315235/reference-for-lie-algebra-valued-differential-forms